# Strange H.264 NAL headers

Tags: h.264

I'm trying to process an MP4 which contains video NAL that are using a strange code in the header, and no start code prefix. It looks like that (by frame number):

```
01:00-00-37-3F-65-B8-4F-DF
02:00-00-00-02-09-30-00-00
03:00-00-00-02-09-30-00-00
04:00-00-00-02-09-30-00-00
05:00-00-00-02-09-30-00-00
[etc]
```

Then each 60 frames, it looks like this:

```
61:00-00-00-02-09-10-00-00
```

So the inter-frame rate seems to be set to 60.

First frame (01) could also begin like this as I cannot really parse it:

```
01:00-00-00-00-00-00-00-10-00-00-37-3F-65-B8-4F-DF
```

What are these headers, and is there a section in the H.264 standard in which I could refer? They are sometime followed by audio (sync-ed).

[EDIT]

Also, further infos: this is produced in WP8, which is using DM355 encoder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MP4 does not use AnnexB. Hence no start codes. The first 4 bytes of each NALU is the size of the NALU in big endian format.

so for example.
    00-00-00-02-09-10-00-00

This is 2 byte NALU of type 9. 9 is an Access Unit delimiter

To get the SPS/PPS you must read the extradata from the avcC atom.

You can read more here:
http://www.szatmary.org/blog/25

Comment: Wow, ok! That makes sense. In the original MP4, I noticed some special codes in the AVCc. Btw, thanks, because I always wanted to know about that but was afraid to ask.

Comment: Reading my comment 3 months later sounded strange. So for friends reading my SO: it's a joke based on his blog post title. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think they are keyframes for the compression. Keyframes every 60  seconds, seems. Not sure about the audio, it seems to be rather inconsistent.